# Using BinaryWriter in a generic class

Tags: c#, delegates

```
[Serializable]
public class Vector3D<T> {
    public T x;
    public T y;
    public T z;
}
```

I have this simple Vector class that's used to store coordinates in various numerical types.

I need to read this from a file and then later store it.

It usually looks something like this:

```
someCoord = new Vector3D<int> {
                x = reader.ReadInt32(),
                y = reader.ReadInt32(),
                z = reader.ReadInt32()
            };
writer.Write(someCoord.x);
writer.Write(someCoord.y);
writer.Write(someCoord.z);
```

I would love to turn those lines into something like this:

```
someCoord = new Vector3D<int>(reader);
someCoord.Write(writer);
```

I would have Read and Write methods ready in the Vector3D class. While writing isn't a problem since I can do something like:

```
writer.Write((T)x)
```

Trying to read in the same fashion becomes a problem since I have to call methods with distinct names, depending on the type I want to read.

All that being said, is there some clever way of still achieving this?
I was thinking about using delegates, but I can't figure out the syntax.

I'd have a dictionary where I'd keep Type-Function(delegate) pairs so that when I want to read something, I call something like:

```
T value = reader.dictionary[T]();
```

where reader is an instance of BinaryReader. If T is int, dictionary[T] would be replaced with readInt32, if T was float, dictionary[T] would be replaced with readSingle, etc.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: This is a little complicated, but doable :             BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);

            Int32[] results = reader.ReadBytes(12).Select((x, i) => new { b = x, index = i / 4 }).GroupBy(x => x.index).Select(x => BitConverter.ToInt32(x.Select(y => y.b).ToArray(),0)).ToArray();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a generic method which relies on the generic type of `<T>`, handles the read, boxes the value and finally returns it. For example:

```
    public static Object GetValue<T>(BinaryReader br) {
        switch (Type.GetTypeCode(typeof(T)))
        {
            case TypeCode.Boolean: { return br.ReadBoolean(); }
            case TypeCode.Byte: { return br.ReadByte(); }
            case TypeCode.Char: { return br.ReadChar(); }
            case TypeCode.Decimal: { return br.ReadDecimal(); }
            case TypeCode.Double: { return br.ReadDouble(); }
            case TypeCode.Int16: { return br.ReadInt16(); }
            case TypeCode.Int32: { return br.ReadInt32(); }
            case TypeCode.Int64: { return br.ReadUInt64(); }
            // Keep on going for other types
            default: { return br.Read(); }
        }
    }
```

Here's a complete example

```
public class Vector3D<T>
{
    public T X { get; set; }
    public T Y { get; set; }
    public T Z { get; set; }
    private readonly String filePath;
    public Vector3D(String filePath) {
        this.filePath = filePath;
        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)) {
                using(BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
                {
                    X = (T) GetValue<T>(br);
                    Y = (T) GetValue<T>(br);
                    Z = (T) GetValue<T>(br);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static Object GetValue<T>(BinaryReader br) {
        switch (Type.GetTypeCode(typeof(T)))
        {
            case TypeCode.Boolean: { return br.ReadBoolean(); }
            case TypeCode.Byte: { return br.ReadByte(); }
            case TypeCode.Char: { return br.ReadChar(); }
            case TypeCode.Decimal: { return br.ReadDecimal(); }
            case TypeCode.Double: { return br.ReadDouble(); }
            case TypeCode.Int16: { return br.ReadInt16(); }
            case TypeCode.Int32: { return br.ReadInt32(); }
            case TypeCode.Int64: { return br.ReadUInt64(); }
            default: { return br.Read(); }
        }
    }
}
```

You can also create an extension method for that:

```
public static class BinaryReaderExtensions
{
    public static Object GetValue(this BinaryReader br, Type type)
    {
        switch (Type.GetTypeCode(type))
        {
            case TypeCode.Boolean: { return br.ReadBoolean(); }
            case TypeCode.Byte: { return br.ReadByte(); }
            case TypeCode.Char: { return br.ReadChar(); }
            case TypeCode.Decimal: { return br.ReadDecimal(); }
            case TypeCode.Double: { return br.ReadDouble(); }
            case TypeCode.Int16: { return br.ReadInt16(); }
            case TypeCode.Int32: { return br.ReadInt32(); }
            case TypeCode.Int64: { return br.ReadUInt64(); }
            default: { return br.Read(); }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Is there any way of doing it without a massive switch case statement?

Comment: Yes there is, but this approach is the safest. Another way would be to read bytes based on the size of the data type, for example an `Int64` is 64-bit long which is equal to 8 Bytes. However, this would be unsafe as the way you may implement it may be buggy.

Comment: Is there a reason for returning `Object` rather than `T`?  You could cast the result like this (I think):  `(T)return br.ReadBoolean();`.  Or am I missing something obvious?  (Wouldn't be the first time!).  _Edit:  Nevermind.  I see you are casting it on the other side of the call._

Comment: @ChrisDunaway: Boxing and unboxing is required here, a type let's say `int` or `Boolean`, etc. can be neither explicitly nor implicitly cast to the type of `T`.